# How to use streamReader(or similar) for a HttpWebResponse stream

Tags: c#, xml, streamreader, httpwebresponse

I am currently trying to retrieve a xml response and parse the result from a web service, but I have ran into issues when receiving the response as a stream and using stream reader to read the result and convert the xml response to a string so it can be parsed to get a result later.

When testing I receive an error that there is illegal characters in path, as the stream reader only accepts a file path not the actual xml response object itself. After extensive searching most of the similar posts on here, most people point to either textreaders or xmlreaders but as the HttpWebResponse returns a stream I can't use those. Does anyone have a idea's or pointers to help me overcome this?

I have included a snippet of the code to how I am handling the response.

```
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());


            string soapResult = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Here is the code for the request, just in case it helps.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Location);
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

            byte[] bytesToWrite = encoding.GetBytes(xml.ToString());
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = bytesToWrite.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8";

            Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);
            newStream.Close();
```

Thanks

Comment: What about  `var myXml = XDocument.Load(responseStream);` ?

Comment: StreamRead defaults os Ascii Encoding which may give errors.  Try UTF8 : StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, this did the trick! feel free to add an answer and i'll vote up your answer.

Comment: @jdweng per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at(v=vs.110).aspx): 'This constructor initializes the encoding to UTF8Encoding'.

Comment: Charles : You must be wrong since the change solved the issue.